# Nikon D80 Mirror Lockup

Tags: nikon, mirror-lockup, nikon-d80

Can I use mirror lockup for long exposures on the Nikon D80?  The option appears to be in the menu, I can't seem to enable it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The D80 has an Exposure Delay mode, which basically adds a 0.4 seconds delay after opening the mirror, then automatically starts the exposure. So it's not a manual step, but just an automatic mirror lockup.
From a quick Google I think it's custom menu open 31.

Comment: I just confirmed on my D80 that it's menu option 31. Help menu explains "Exp. delay mode - select "On" to reduce camera shake due to mirror shock. Delays shutter release until about 0.4 seconds after the mirror is raised."

Answer (score 1):

No you can't. It is only for cleaning the sensor.

If you want to do long exposure shot, you can select the manual mode and roll the rear wheel in 'bulb mode' (after 30").

Comment: I was hoping for mirror lockup to reduce vibration due to mirror slap.  Thanks!

Comment: For this, you have to use the "exp. delay mode" option in the settings menu. It will delays shutter release until after the mirror is raised.